# Spring controller is not being called

Tags: spring, spring-mvc, http-status-code-404

I am new in spring application. I am trying to create small spring application but I am getting 404 error message. Seems like controller (indexController) is not begin called. I tired to debug but its not going there.

**Files location:**

/WebContent/WEB-INF/pages/index.html

/WebContent/WEB-INF/HelloWeb-servlet.xml

/WebContent/WEB-INF/web.xml

---

HelloWeb-servlet.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns:context="http://www.springframework.org/schema/context"
xmlns:mvc="http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc"
xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans-4.0.xsd
    http://www.springframework.org/schema/context http://www.springframework.org/schema/context/spring-context-4.0.xsd
    http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc/spring-mvc-4.0.xsd">

<mvc:annotation-driven />

<context:component-scan base-package="com.requestengine.controller" />
```

IndexController.java

```
package com.requestengine.controller;

import org.springframework.stereotype.Controller;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RequestMapping;

@Controller
public class IndexController {
@RequestMapping("/")
public String index(){
    return "index";
}
```

### }

web.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<web-app xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns="http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/javaee" xsi:schemaLocation="http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/javaee http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/javaee/web-app_3_1.xsd" id="WebApp_ID" version="3.1">
<display-name></display-name>
<servlet>
<servlet-name>HelloWeb</servlet-name>
<servlet-class>org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet</servlet-class>
<load-on-startup>1</load-on-startup>
</servlet>
<servlet-mapping>
<servlet-name>HelloWeb</servlet-name>
<url-pattern>*.html</url-pattern>
<url-pattern>*.htm</url-pattern>
<url-pattern>*.jason</url-pattern>
<url-pattern>*.xml</url-pattern>
```

Comment: Specify base package for component scan as package, not a class (and certainly skip the `.java` extension): `base-package="com.requestengine.controller"`

Comment: I was testing that, forgot to remove here. But still I am getting 404 error.

Comment: try adding the following to your 'HelloWeb-servlet.xml' <beans:bean class="org.springframework.web.servlet.view.InternalResourceViewResolver">
     <beans:property name="prefix" value="/WEB-INF/pages/" />
<beans:property name="suffix" value=".html" />
    </beans:bean>

Comment: @Upendra also within my web.xml 'servlet' tags I have the following   <init-param>
   <param-name>contextConfigLocation</param-name>
   <param-value>classpath:com/sga/app/xml/dispatcher-servlet.xml</param-value>
  </init-param> I suggest you move your Helloweb-servlet.xml onto the classpath, i.e.inside  /WEB-INF/classes or inside the /src folder

Comment: If you are new to spring , try spring boot with spring data rest . Spring boot is almost zero xml config . It will automatically expose you entities as well .

Answer (score 0):

HTTP 404 means the URL is not found:

https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/HTTP_404

It usually tells me that my packaging or mapping or request URL is incorrect.

Start with the basics: write an index.html page and see that it's displayed.

It's not typical to have an index controller.  Once you have that page working, see if you can map to something meaningful.

Is that controller in a package?  I don't see a package statement at the top.  It's impossible to be a Spring developer without being a solid Java developer first.  No one would create a class without a package.

Answer (score 0):

I modified your code a bit to make it work.

### web.xml

```
 <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
    <web-app xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns="http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/javaee" xsi:schemaLocation="http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/javaee http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/javaee/web-app_3_1.xsd" id="WebApp_ID" version="3.1">
    <display-name></display-name>
    <servlet>
    <servlet-name>HelloWeb</servlet-name>
    <servlet-class>org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet</servlet-class>
        <init-param>
            <param-name>contextConfigLocation</param-name>
            <param-value>/WEB-INF/HelloWeb-servlet.xml</param-value>
        </init-param>
    <load-on-startup>1</load-on-startup>
    </servlet>
    <servlet-mapping>
    <servlet-name>HelloWeb</servlet-name>
    <url-pattern>*.htm</url-pattern>
    </servlet-mapping>
</web-app>
```

### IndexController.java

```
package com.requestengine.controller;

import org.springframework.stereotype.Controller;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RequestMapping;

@Controller
public class IndexController {
@RequestMapping("/")
@ResponseBody
public String index(){
    return "index";
}
```